# Python+Pygame glibc error

Tags: python, pygame

I've recently started doing some coding in Python again and I've encountered an error which I simply don't know how to interpret.

Source code:
http://paste.lisp.org/display/123261

Error:
http://paste.lisp.org/display/123270

The problem arises when I call program_loop() and it's probably related to the class I've written too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I didn't closely look at your code, but the error means there was something so f*cked up in Python it crashed through an error in C. It wasn't even able to catch something and handle it, and this should never happen with the interpreter. Please report this bug to pygame.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I suspected, reinstalling Pygame didn't work so it's not my installation that was corrupt or anything.